# Fractional integral with two parameters

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

How can i find the exact value of $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {{{{x^m}} \over {1 + {x^p}}}dx} $$
with $p < m + 1$. Thank you.

Comment: What are $p$ and $m$? Real numbers? Positive integers? Also, show us what you've tried and where you got stuck

Comment: yes, m and p are positive reals. I can't even start,  can you give me some hints. Thanx

Comment: does the integral converge, for $p<m+1$? i think it does not

Comment: Actually, $\int\limits_0^\infty  {{{{x^m}} \over {1 + {x^p}}}dx}\leq c+\int\limits_1^\infty  {{{{x^{m-p}}}}dx}=\frac{x^{m-p+1}}{(m-p+1)}|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}=\infty$

Comment: Exuse me. I meen p>m+1...sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Through the substitution $\frac{1}{1+x^p}=u$ the given integral boils down to a value of [Euler's Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), namely
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{1+x^p}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{p\sin\left(\frac{\pi(m+1)}{p}\right)} $$
due to the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function.
 The above identity holds as soon as $\text{Re}(m)>-1$ and $\text{Re}(m-p)<-1$.